# Objective C: Passing variables between controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to pass some variables from my ViewController to my TableViewController, where they can be displayed. For example, say I want to pass a string firstName:

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)addToListPressed:(id)sender {
    TableViewController *tableController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    tableController.firstName = @"Alice";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableController animated:YES];  
}
```

TableViewController.h

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property NSString *firstName;

@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSLog(@"First name: %@", self.firstName);
}
```

The output I get is First name: (null) How can I access the name correctly?

Comment: Try changing the property to `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;`.

Comment: Still came out as (null)

Comment: Use the debugger and see if viewDidLoad is called before you set the property. If it is, see why. The init method should load the view.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm completely new to Objective C and am not too sure how to debug. However, the name property is set when a button is pressed, and I do that before I press another button, which displays the TableViewController. TableViewController also has the log statement at the top, and I don't see that log statement until I click the button to load TableViewController.

Comment: to add a breakpoint, click in the small column to the left of your code where the line numbers are (if showing) it will make a blue mark, then your code will stop there when its about to execute that line. you can inspect all the variables at that point in the code in the debug window at the bottom, check that the `tableviewController` has that property set before and after the segue, and if the table view controller is the exact same instance before and after as well. your code as it stands looks like it should work

Comment: Whoever is down voting answers, please leave a comment to explain your actions.  I'm pretty sure @Abhinav answer will work.

Comment: try to use @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName; This will retain the object and you'll get the value firstName.

Comment: @NirmitDagly please read the first two comments below the question.

Comment: @rmaddy There is a use of "retain" property instead of "copy". Read the comment properly.

Comment: @NirmitDagly I know you said `retain`. My point is, if `copy` didn't help, `retain` certainly won't either.

Comment: @rmaddyHave you tried it at least once?

Answer (score 0):

## Final Update

I actually added your code to my project because I was curious, and it ran without a problem.  I include it commented out in the github project.  Enjoy!

## Update

I have created a github repo here: https://github.com/Rnorback/sample-segue-code that will show you exactly how to setup your viewcontroller and tableview for the future.

I added this code to the ViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tableViewSegue"]) {
        TableViewController *tableVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        tableVC.firstName = @"Alice";
    }
}
```

And I added this code to a button action from in ViewController.m:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tableViewSegue" sender:self];
```

**To setup this project I did exactly what I describe below:**

In the storyboard setup the following boards:
[image]

Make sure they are linked to your two classes in the identity inspector:
[image]

[image]

Then control-drag between them to create a segue and select show:
[image]

Finally, name that segue in the attributes inspector:
[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I came across Segues when trying to figure out my problem, but I still don't understand how this works. What do I write as destinationViewController? do I put the second piece of code in the viewDidLoad of TableViewController?

Comment: Simply download the zip of the github repo in my answer and that should help clarify.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not intended to allow external classes to read your table view's first name then please move it in the implementation file like this:

**TableViewController.m**

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;

@end


- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)iFirstName {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.firstName = iFirstName;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"First name: %@", self.firstName);
}
```

And then call your `TableViewController` like this:

```
- (IBAction)addToListPressed:(id)sender {
    TableViewController *tableController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Alice")];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableController animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT: Post comment from OP**

I believe this is all about right object being loaded in memory. If you are doing it via storyboard then from your view controller (that passes name on tap on button) drag the segue to your `UITableViewController`. Take a look at this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) on how to do this in storyboard.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    TableViewController *myTableController = (TableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    myTableController.firstName = @"Alice";
}
```

And then do not implement the `initWithFirstName:` method as I had suggested earlier. Make your `TableViewController.h` look like this.

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;

@end
```

Comment: This seems to make more sense, but unfortunately, I'm still getting (null) :/

Comment: Interesting, could you please put a break point in the init method just before return statement and check the value inside `self.firstName `. Also, are you using storyboard to connect your TableViewController there?

Comment: Comes out as @"Alice", so it's working there. I am using storyboard. Frankly, I'm not too sure how it connects altogether, but I have a button in ViewController (connected from Main.storyboard) that makes the the table view defined in TableViewController pop up. Everything in the table view is working just fine.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated post. Let me know if this works. I shall then edit my post to delete earlier suggested solution.